# (Dojo 1.10) URL returned by dojoLoader seems wrong/inconsistent, how can I configure this correctly?

Tags: dojo

We recently updated our server with signed certificates and changed the base URL from https://servername/ to https://servername.domain.info/ . This has broken module loading in Dojo and I can't seem to correct it. The current config looks like this:

```
var dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        packages: [
            {
                name: "js",
                location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + 'Scripts'
            },
            {
                name: "widgets",
                location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + 'Scripts/widgets'
            },
            {
                name: "dgrid",
                location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + 'Scripts/3.14/dgrid'
            },
            {
                name: "dijit",
                location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + 'Scripts/3.14/dijit'
            }
        ]
};
```

This used to work, and it still works on my dev machine when the root URL is just 'localhost'. Looking at the errors in the console it seems to be trying to find the modules at https://servername/ instead of https://servername.domain.info/ and I've tried everything I could find to point it in the right direction, including setting `baseUrl: 'https://servername.domain.info'` explicitly. Anything I've tried results in different URL strings, sometimes just the pathname and no base URL, sometimes pathname plus protocol with no domain info, etc. For reference, I also tried just adding the server URL to each location's URL string and I get the same error that seems to drop all but the first word from the server domain name.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I'm baffled by what dojoLoader decides to drop. I've read and reread the documentation but not much is said about how the base URL is calculated as far as I can find, just stuff on how to set baseUrl in the config to something.

edit: Per the comment below, I realize more info is needed. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and publishing to Windows Server 2012 R2 running IIS (v7 iirc). It does look like maybe Visual Studio is messing with the URL somehow, Dojo is not to blame. I was able to work around it by editing the file directly on the server and setting a location URL for every package (and their dependencies). I'd still like to know why it's happening and how I can set it up correctly.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - ProjectName</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/3.14/esri/css/esri.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/map.css" />
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>
```

Comment: `location.pathname` doesn't even include the hostname, so the code above would only produce host-relative URLs.  There's no way it could be switching the hostname on you.  If you specify a full absolute URL, there's no way Dojo would be mutilating the hostname itself either.  There's got to be more to this story...  Can you provide the full page that Dojo is being loaded into (or at least the full `head` to start)?

Comment: I thought that was right, glad I'm not completely insane. I updated the question with some more info.